# QGIS saving layer

Tags: layer, qgis

the following might be a stupid question, but given that I am new at this I just cannot seem to find an answer.
I have several selected feautures from different layers in QGIS Desktop 3.10.14 and would need to save these to a new layer. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the layer->Export->Save Selected Features as

[image]